# Locus of a point Question

Tags: euclidean-geometry, locus

The triangle abc is circumscribed in the circle o. The altitudes bb1 and cc1 intersect at h. If bc is fixed and point a moves on the arc bac, determine the locus of point h.

my attempt quadrilateral ab1hc1 is circumbscribed therefore a+h=180. since angle a is constant and equal to bc/2 therefore angle h is constant and equal to 180-bc/2...

Comment: Please edit your post to fix the incoherence between minor and capital letters.

Comment: And since you've found that the angle h is constant, what is the locus of h? What other restrictions are there to consider?